# UnboundLocalError after user inputs last piece of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Finishing up a database project and I'm having issues w/ it all coming together. I keep getting the below error after the user inputs the final data request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/j/Documents/Ashford U/CPT 200/Python Code/CPT 200 - Wk 5 Final Project JC.py", line 72, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:/Users/j/Documents/Ashford U/CPT 200/Python Code/CPT 200 - Wk 5 Final Project JC.py", line 42, in main
    if employee_found is None:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'employee_found' referenced before assignment
```

The user is to be able to input the requested data and it loop to the main question of adding, viewing, querying, or editing. So far its not looping back and I'm not sure where I've gotten off the wrong track at. Any help is much appreciated as I still have to add in the ability to write this to a file. Code below.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, ssn, phone, email, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.ssn = ssn
        self.phone = phone
        self.email = email
        self.salary = salary

def add():
    name = input("Please enter the employee's name: ")
    ssn = input("Please enter the employee's ssn: ")
    phone = str(input("Please enter the employee's phone number xxx-xxx-xxxx: "))
    email = input("Please enter the employee's email: ")
    salary = str(input("Please enter the employee's salary: "))
    return Employee(name, ssn, phone, email, salary)

def formatEmployee(employee, name, ssn, phone, email, salary):
    print(f'---------------------------- {name} -----------------------------')
    print(f'SSN: {ssn}')
    print(f'Phone: {phone}')
    print(f'Email: {email}')
    print(f'Salary: {salary}')
    print('------------------------------------------------------------------------')


def main():
    employee_list = []
    #Loop of questions to add, search, edit, ect.
    while True:
        user_input = input('Please enter a command (add, view, query, edit): ')
        if user_input == 'add':
            new_employee = add()
            employee_list.append(new_employee)
            print(f'There are now ({(len(employee_list))}) employees in the database.')
        if user_input == 'view':
            for employee in employee_list:
                #prints(employee_list)
                formatEmployee(employee)
        if user_input == 'find':
            ssn = input('Enter employee SSN:')
            employee_found = find(ssn, employee_list)
        if employee_found is None:
            print('Employee not found')
        else:
            formatEmployee(employee_found)
        if user_input == 'edit':
            ssn = input('Enter SSN of employee to edit their info: ')
            employee_found = find(ssn, employee_list)
            edit_field = input('Please enter the employee information that you want to edit: ')
            new_info = input(f'Please enter the new: {edit_field}')
            print('edit complete!')
# Employee edit branches
def edit(info, newinfo, employee):
    if info == 'name':
        employee.name = newinfo
    if info == 'ssn':
        employee.ssn = newinfo
    if info == 'phone':
        employee.phone = newinfo
    if info == 'email':
        employee.email = newinfo
    if info == 'salary':
        employee.salary = newinfo

#Query by SSN of employee
def find(ssn, employee_list):
    for employee in employee_list:
        if ssn == employee.ssn:
            return employee
            return None

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your indentation... your `main` function should look like this:

```
def main():
    employee_list = []
    #Loop of questions to add, search, edit, ect.
    while True:
        user_input = input('Please enter a command (add, view, query, edit): ')
        if user_input == 'add':
            new_employee = add()
            employee_list.append(new_employee)
            print(f'There are now ({(len(employee_list))}) employees in the database.')
        if user_input == 'view':
            for employee in employee_list:
                #prints(employee_list)
                formatEmployee(employee)
        if user_input == 'find':
            ssn = input('Enter employee SSN:')
            employee_found = find(ssn, employee_list)
            if employee_found is None:
                print('Employee not found')
            else:
                formatEmployee(employee_found)
        if user_input == 'edit':
            ssn = input('Enter SSN of employee to edit their info: ')
            employee_found = find(ssn, employee_list)
            edit_field = input('Please enter the employee information that you want to edit: ')
            new_info = input(f'Please enter the new: {edit_field}')
            print('edit complete!')
```